# Compiler can't recognise setOnClickListener(....);

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I was creating button in ActivityMain.java 
Compiler was unable to recognise onSetClickListener. What am I missing?

```
package com.example.mydiceapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.blahblah);

    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());

}
```

Comment: Hi, could you also provide the compiler output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is returning an error because you placed actionable code outside a method. If you look closely, you'd see that the line generating the error is not enclosed inside any method.

With the exception of variable declarations and assignment, actions are meant to be enclosed inside methods. Therefore, having a `setOnClickListener` call which is not enclosed in any method would obviously not work. Simply move these two lines inside your `onCreate()` method and everything would be fine. Here's an illustration:

```
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.blahblah);
     rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
}

...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `findViewById()` and use `setOnClickListener()` inside `onCreate()` method

Try this

```
package com.example.mydiceapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.blahblah);

         rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
    }




}
```

Comment: @LovishBadlani Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `onCreate()`:

```
Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.blahblah);
rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should use setOnClickListener() inside onCreate() method**

```
package com.example.mydiceapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.blahblah);
    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // Do anything 
        }
    });

}
```